# SpriteKit & Swift: Changing size of scrolling ground node depending on screen size does not work

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Im working on a game where i have a scrolling ground node, does anyone now how i could change the size of the ground node depending on which device it is running? I have a method to determine on which device the game is running on and changing the size of all the other nodes in my game works great exept for the ground node. I tried to do it but without success.

Thank you in advance.

**Method to determine on which device the game is running on:**

```
func determineDevice() {

    if view!.bounds.width == 480.0 { //IP4
        isIphone4 = true
        isIphone5 = false
        isIphone6 = false
        isIphone6Plus = false
    }

    if view!.bounds.width == 568.0 { //IP5
        isIphone4 = false
        isIphone5 = true
        isIphone6 = false
        isIphone6Plus = false
    }

    if view!.bounds.width == 667.0 { //IP6
        isIphone4 = false
        isIphone5 = false
        isIphone6 = true
        isIphone6Plus = false
    }

    if view!.bounds.width == 736.0 { //IP6+
        isIphone4 = false
        isIphone5 = false
        isIphone6 = false
        isIphone6Plus = true
    }
}
```

**Here's an example how i set the size of all other nodes in my game depending on the screen size:**

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

  var screenWidth:CGFloat = 0
  var screenHeight:CGFloat = 0

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    screenWidth = self.view!.bounds.width
    screenHeight = self.view!.bounds.height 

    node.size = CGSizeMake(screenWidth / 5.5, screenHeight / 6) 
}
```

}

**Last but not least, the ground code:**

```
func initializingScrollingGround() {
    for var index = 0; index < 2; index += 1 {
        ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Ground_Layer")
        ground.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height  / 6)
        ground.position = CGPoint(x: index * Int(ground.size.width), y: Int(screenHeight - 37))
        ground.zPosition = 10
        ground.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        ground.name = "Ground"

        let offsetX = ground.size.width * ground.anchorPoint.x
        let offsetY = ground.size.height * ground.anchorPoint.y

        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0 - offsetX, 48 - offsetY)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0 - offsetX, 0 - offsetY)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 665 - offsetX, 0 - offsetY)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 668 - offsetX, 48 - offsetY)

        CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

        ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path)
        ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ground
        ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        ground.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        ground.physicsBody?.restitution = 0


        self.worldNode.addChild(ground)
    }
}
```

**In the update method:**

```
 func moveGround() {
    self.worldNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("Ground", usingBlock: { (node, stop) -> Void in
        if let Ground = node as? SKSpriteNode {
            Ground.position = CGPoint(x: Ground.position.x - self.groundVelocity, y: Ground.position.y)

            // Checks if ground node is completely scrolled off the screen, if yes, then puts it at the end of the other node.
            if Ground.position.x <= -Ground.size.width {
                Ground.position = CGPointMake(Ground.position.x + Ground.size.width * 2, Ground.position.y)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Does anyone now how i could solve my problem?

Comment: are you working in resizeFill scaleMode?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon no, with AspectFill

Comment: ok, then your approach is all wrong.  The goal of scaleMode, (with the exception of resizeFill), is to have 1 scene size that scales across any aspect and size.  Basically your "screen size" is your scene's size, and the length and height of an individual pixel will be determined by the scale difference of your scene size, to your actual screen size, if this makes any sense to you

Comment: to keep the numbers simple,  lets say that on a real device, 1 pixel is 1 inch, and there are 10 pixels in a row.  You make a scene size of 5 pixels in a row.  When scaling happens, 1 pixel will be 2 inches in length,  so that we can fit the 5 pixels in the 10 pixel length.  If we go to a device that has 15 pixels, then the scene will have 1 pixel at 3 inches in length.

Comment: so if you want to have a unique non scalled background on all of your devices,  you would need to use the .resizeFill scaleMode, since that does not scale.  Now, we can cheat the system.  If the goal is to only have a unique background, but still have the scene scale, then we can set the scene background to transparent, and use a UIImageView to show the custom background based on device size

Comment: @Knight0fDragon i think i unterstand what you're saying and it makes sence to me. but since im creating the whole game only with code and without storyboards, except launscreen.storyboard how could use the UIImageView in my GameScene?

Comment: You have a view controller,  I am going to assume in the view did load you are presenting the scene.  Well instead of making SKView the default root view for your view controller,  you make a UIView.  Then in this UIView, you attach the UIImageView, followed by the SKView that will house your scene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Alright, im going to try that right now and report the outcome to you, i know how to do all that except of adding an SKView to an UIView. how can i do that?

Comment: Same way you add any view to a UIView,  nothing is different

Comment: @Knight0fDragon ok, i never worked with views before, im gonna google how that works. be right back. thank you

Comment: Do not take offense,  that was a brilliant response,  I wish more people would think like that.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon dont worry, im not taking any offense and im glad that you took time to answer my question and help me out :) - anyway, i dont now how long its gonna take to learn/do that. it will take some time. i'll be back when im done

Comment: btw, since you mentioned that you are doing this all in code, when you create your scene,  use a specific size, not the view size, so `GameScene(size:CGSize(width:750:height:1334))`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon hi, sorry unfortunately i had no time yesterday. regarding the size, wouldnt this size be to small for the iphone 6 plus? and when im changing the size like that it messes up the whole game and everything is too big or to small. right now im setting the size of the Scene like this: `let skView = self.view as! SKView; let myScene = StartScene(size: skView.bounds.size)`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon And regarding to the UIView,  in my GameScene i have 2 scrolling backgrounds behind my scrolling ground node that means i have to put the two backgrounds in two other UImageViews aswell right? And if understood everything correctly the hierarchy would be `UIViewController->UIView->UIImageView->SKView` correct? And one thing i still dont understand is how would i connect the images of the UIImageViews with the code that triggers the scrolling of the background & ground nodes in my GameScene?

Comment: no, I have already explained how scaling works,  you said you understood it LOL,  the game will automatically scale up

Comment: you never should set the scene to your skView size,  this defeats the purpose of it,  You should always have a static size,  and if you need the size to vary by device, use the .resizeFill scale mode

Comment: UIImageView was not recommended for scrolling backgrounds,  just backgrounds that you wanted to have higher definition for while maintaining the same size across device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125792/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-icod3r).

Answer (score 0):

One approach to try is with `SKCameraNode`, then all your nodes will change together. This example uses an extension on `SKCameraNode` and distinquishes only between iPad and iPhone;

```
// SKCameraNode+Extensions.swift
extension SKCameraNode {
    func updateScaleFor(userInterfaceIdiom: UIUserInterfaceIdiom, isLandscape: Bool) {
        switch userInterfaceIdiom {
            case .phone:
                self.setScale(isLandscape ? 0.75 : 1.0)
            case .pad:
                self.setScale(isLandscape ? 1.0 : 1.25)
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Then when your scene loads;

```
camera.updateScaleFor(userInterfaceIdiom: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom, isLandscape: true)
```